# How to run javascript in sandbox mode using V8 on server?

Tags: javascript, sandbox, v8

Can someone kindly guide me so as to how to setup sandbox mode using V8 to run unfrendly javascript code on server ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use an existing [sandbox](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox) module. Writing your own is painful.

As per docs

```
var s = new Sandbox()
s.run( '1 + 1 + " apples"', function( output ) {
  // output.result == "2 apples"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but the module suggested is meant to be used with node.js, where as we need to run unfriendly code on server using v8. Can the same module be used with v8 also ?

Comment: @MohammedKhan your question is tagged node.js. Y u v8 instead of node.js

Comment: I have removed the node.js tag, it was a mix up.

Comment: Note: gf3 sandbox can be broken out of.

Comment: That makes it not much of a sandbox.  Do you have proof of this, @Petah?